# How to find and replace string in a file using input of line number in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, file, replace, find

My requirement is to find a file from a directory and then in that file find LOG_X_PARAMS and in that append a string after the first comma this is what i am having for now

```
import os, fnmatch
def findReplacelist(directory, finds, new_string, file):
    line_number = 0
    list_of_results = []
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(directory)):
        if file in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(path, file)
            with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
                for line in f:
                    line_number += 1
                    if finds in line:
                        list_of_results.append((line_number))
    print(list_of_results)


def get_git_root(path):
    Path = "E:\Code\modules"
    file_list=["pb_sa_ch.c"]
    for i in file_list:
        findReplacelist(Path , "LOG_1_PARAMS", "instance", i)
```

The example line is below change

```
LOG_X_PARAMS(string 1, string 2); #string1 andd string2 is random
```

this to

```
LOG_X_PARAMS(string 1, new_string, string 2);
```

I can find the line number using LOG_X_PARAMS now using this line number I need to append a string in the same line can someone help solving it ?

Comment: Please supply the expected [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") . We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points. This allows testing suggestions against your data and desired output.

Comment: yaa i have added example thank you @itprorh66

Comment: Sorry to continue harassing you, but your example doesn't constitute a MRE.  We need to see, example data, a good faith effort and a solution, a output which illustrates your problem and what expected output should look like.  Unfortunately, you have not provided the necessary information.

Comment: I hope i have given the excepted MRE this is my first time using Stackoverflow so i am new to this platform

Comment: So, clearly I am still a little confused.   ```findReplacelist```  produces a list_of_results which seems to be a list of target lines to be changed based on identifying finds within the line.  Is what you want to do at this point  write the file back with changes updated to the lines identified in ```list_of_results'''?

Comment: Yes that's what I want, if there is a better way of do it I am ok to change it, the input I can have inputs only directory, file names, and find and new_string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do the task.  I would find the files I want to change, read then file line by line and if there is a change in the file, then write the file back out.  Heres the approach:

```
def findReplacelist(directory, finds, new_string, file):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(directory)):
        if file in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(path, file)
            find_replace(finds, new_string, filepath)  

def find_replace(tgt_phrase, new_string, file):
    outfile = ''
    chgflg = False
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if tgt_phrase in line:
                outfile += line + new_string
                chgflg = True
            else:
                outfile += line
    if chgflg:
        with open(file, 'w') as f:
            f.write(outfile)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort but its working in different way like 
LOG_x_PARAMS(string 1, string 2);
, Instance,
the new string is in next line and the output is expected to be like this 
LOG_x_PARAMS(string 1, Instance, string 2); after the first comma
so I changed this 
outfile += line.replace(",", new_string)